# Show that $\{x\in V| \langle x,e \rangle=0 \forall e\in E\} =\{y\in V ~| ~y\perp w_i, 1\leq i \leq k \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, inner-products

> Let $E$ be  subset of a vector space $V$. Let $B =\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ be a basis for $E$. Prove: $E^\perp =\{y\in V | y\perp w_i, 1\leq i \leq k \}$

Is my proof correct?

Define two sets:

(a) $E_1 = \{x\in V| \langle x,e \rangle=0 \forall e\in E\}$

(b) $E_2 =\{y\in V ~| ~y\perp w_i, 1\leq i \leq k \}$

I need to show that those two sets are equal. First, I show that $E_1\subseteq E_2$

$v\in E_1 \implies \langle v,e\rangle=0 \forall e$

since $w_1,\dots,w_k\in E$, then by definition $\langle v,w_i\rangle=0 \forall i$. Hence $v\in E_2$

Now, we need to show $E_2\subseteq E_1$:

$v\in E_2 \implies \langle v,w_i\rangle=0 \forall i$ 
hence, 
$$
c_1\langle v,w_1\rangle +\dots +c_k\langle v,w_k \rangle =0\\
\langle v,c_1 w_1+\dots c_k w_k\rangle =0\\
\langle v,e\rangle=0 \forall e\in E
\implies  v\in E_1 \implies E_1=E_2
$$

Comment: Looks alright to me.

Comment: My only comment would be to use more words. For example, for the second inclusion, it would be more clear if you said: 
Let $v \in E_2$. If $e \in E$, then we can write $e = c_1 w_1 + \dots + c_k w_k$ for some scalars $c_i$, and then $\langle v,e \rangle = \langle v,c_1 w_1 + \dots + c_k w_k \rangle = c_1\langle v,w_1 \rangle + \dots + c_k \langle v,w_k \rangle = 0$, so $v \in E_2$.

Comment: A small suggestion for future problems: include a word or two in the title. When it's all math, it makes it harder to actually get to the problem-page in some browsers.

Comment: (I've just realised, regarding my earlier comment, the final bit should say "so $v \in E_1$".